# How to connect to MSSQL using MAMP and php

Tags: php, sql-server, mamp

Could someone tell how to connect to MSSQL using php? I am running a MAMP server and using php as server language. I have no problem connecting to MySQL. But recently there is another database we are using which is in MSSQL. But when I replaced the connection command from `mysqli_connect` to `mssql_connect` browser is throwing out the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\MAMP\htdocs\xxx\xxxxx.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\xxx\xxxxx.php on line 8

Answer (score 0):

`mssql_connect()` was removed in PHP 7.0.0

Have a look at PHP manual at:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php
You should use one of the following:

`PDO::__construct()` or `sqlsrv_connect()` or`odbc_connect()`

Comment: I already tried those. But it doesn't even taking those as commands. The colour codes are not changing. Also page showing same error